# Retrieving data from Firebase without duplicates

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using multiple loops to pull data from firebase, but it results in pulling duplicate data. What's the best way to solve this issue?

```
func fetchPost(completion: @escaping ([Post])->()) {
    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("Topics").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "myId")
        postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var resultsArray = [Post]()
            var topicIdArray = [Any]()
                for topic in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let topicId = topic.childSnapshot(forPath: "topicId").value
                    topicIdArray.append(topicId)
                        for element in topicIdArray {
                            let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "topic").queryEqual(toValue: element)
                                postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                    for child in snapshot.children {
                                        let post = Post(snapshot: child as! DataSnapshot)
                                        resultsArray.append(post)

                                    }
                                    completion(resultsArray)
                                })

                        }
                }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: ObserveSingleEvent is the correct answer but looking further into the code, are you intentionally adding an observer to every post? `postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in`? That would mean that any time anything changes in the */posts* node they will all reload and append to the array... over and over.

Comment: yes good point. To fix this, should I add a bracket after the first for loop? for topic in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let topicId = topic.childSnapshot(forPath: "topicId").value
                    topicIdArray.append(topicId) } for element in topicIdArray...

Comment: No. If you are just looking to add posts one time and not leave an observer to fire future events, use .observeSingleEvent. Also, Firebase doesn't do well in tight loops with many iterations; so this `for element in topicIdArray` loop may become problematic in the future. You may want to consider denormalizing your data so instead of having to loop like that, your queries pull in the specific data you need. This is why I am not in love with the accepted answer - it solves part of the issue but creates much deeper problems and isn't really addressing the overall design. Just my .02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Observe Single Event to avoid duplication

```
func fetchPost(completion: @escaping ([Post])->()) {
    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("Topics").queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "myId")
        postRef.observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var resultsArray = [Post]()
            var topicIdArray = [Any]()
                for topic in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let topicId = topic.childSnapshot(forPath: "topicId").value
                    topicIdArray.append(topicId)
                        for element in topicIdArray {
                            let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "topic").queryEqual(toValue: element)
                                postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                                    for child in snapshot.children {
                                        let post = Post(snapshot: child as! DataSnapshot)
                                        resultsArray.append(post)

                                    }
                                    completion(resultsArray)
                                })

                        }
                }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: `postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in` would mean that any time ANYTHING changes in the */posts* node they will all reload and append to the array... over and over.

Comment: for that ... you should maintain your model accordingly

Comment: lol. You missed my point. If there are 10,000 posts in the posts node, and *one* post title is updated, all 10,000 posts will reload *in addition* to the ones already in the array. e.g posts 1-10,000 are loaded and stored the resultsArray. A title changes and posts 1-10,000 load again and are appended to the array. So now there's 20,000 posts in the array and the second 10,000 are a duplicate of the first 10,000 (except the one with a different title).